# Open in a new window in yii2 [For a button dropdown]

Tags: yii2

how can one open a link in a new tab. in my case i wanna do it in the following code

```
if( Yii::$app->session->get('department_id') == 5 )
                                    {
                                        $items[]    =   ['label' => 'Offer Letter',
                                        'url' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['dashboard/print_offer_letter', 'id' => $data->id]),

                                        ];
```

i tried like this but didn't work

```
$items[]    =   ['label' => 'Offer Letter', ['title'=>'go','target'=>'_blank'],
                                        'url' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['dashboard/print_offer_letter', 'id' => $data->id]),

                                        ];
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you trying to do this in NavBar?

Comment: its a button dropdown

Comment: check my answer .. haven't tried it .. but it worked for me in navbar .. try it and let me know if it works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use something like below:

```
$items[] = [
            'label' => 'items',
            'url' => Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['dashboard/print_offer_letter', 'id' => $data->id]),
            'linkOptions' => ['target'=>'_blank']
        ];
```